# SQL Customer Order

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT u.name, count(user_id) AS "Num_Apperence",YEAR(t.created_at)
             FROM transactions t
             LEFT JOIN users u 
             ON t.user_id = u.id
             WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = 2019
             GROUP BY u.name
             HAVING count(user_id) > 3
)
SELECT Name1
FROM (SELECT u.name AS 'Name1', count(user_id) AS "Num_Apperence",YEAR(t.created_at)
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = 2020
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING count(user_id) > 3) AS T
INNER JOIN CTE 
ON CTE.name = T.Name1
```

This can run successfully, but cannot pass the test case. I looked up both query results, seems find, I couldn't find what is the problem

Comment: You need more details about what you expected and the test cases that it needs to pass, and table schema..

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: The question is in the image, please click the top image

Comment: Do NOT rely on images in your question. Take the time to supply text. Please refer to  the extensive help found in the page footer

Comment: `CTE.name = T.Name1`are you sure name is unique? You should join on user id

Comment: The question ask for number of transactions, I suppose each transaction might have multiple items, to count correctly you need to use `count(distinct transactions.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Customers with more than 3 orders in 2019 & 2020, output just the name:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM (
    SELECT
          t.user_id
    FROM transactions t
    WHERE t.created_at >= '2019-01-01' AND t.created_at < '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY t.user_id
    HAVING count(case when year(t.created_at) = 2019 then 1 end) > 3
       AND count(case when year(t.created_at) = 2020 then 1 end) > 3
    ) AS uc
LEFT JOIN users u ON uc.user_id = u.id
```

1. It isn't necessary to have aggregates in the select clause of a query using `group by`
2. avoid using functions in where clause predicates to make best use of indexes. It is possible to use `WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) IN (2019,2020)` but this probably would not make use of any index on that date column.
3. filter the transactions to just the 2 years wanted (2019 & 2020)
4. by performing the aggregation prior to joining tables may help performance

Comment: You provided a completely different query compared to the one in the question. Some explanation on why the one in the question is wrong and why your is good would be great.

Comment: without the actual test case and data I  don't know for certain what the problem is with the existing query. So I used an approach that I would adopt for the requirement. It aggregates across a single table in a single pass of that table, so it should perform well assuming reasonable indexing. The main logic is in the having clause which requires that any returned row have more than 3 rows in transactions in both years.